# Laravel Trying to get property 'name' of non-object. Where problem?

Tags: php, laravel

I try to save in database information, which i received via API.

I try to save `name`, `ratings` and `platforms` in database, which comes in `results` array. `Ratings` received in array, `platforms`, how i understand received in double arrays.

I try to make something like this:

```
    $response = \Rawg::load('games')->setParams([
        'page' => 1,
        'page_size' => 40,
        'ordering' => '-rating',
    ])->get();

    foreach ($response as $result) {
        Games::insert(
            ['name' => $result->name, 'ratings' => $result->ratings->title, 'platforms' => $result->platforms->platform['name']]
        );
    }
```

But i received error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`. Where can be my problem? I'll be glad to get help.

Comment: `foreach ($response['results'] as $result)` ?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto already try it, same error: `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`

Comment: Can you `dd($response)`? or Is the result in the image the result of `$response`?

Comment: yes, i update my question with new screenshots with `dd($response)`

Comment: looks like it is an array, not an object...

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code! Code is text; copy, paste and format into your question (this includes output from debugging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an array not an object, and needs to change `$response` :

```
foreach ($response['results'] as $result) {
    Games::insert([
        'name' => $result['name'], 
        'ratings' => $result['ratings'][0]['title'], 
        'platforms' => $result['platforms'][0]['platform']['name']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: hm, now i received: `Undefined index: title`

Comment: Not visible in the picture. Try my update. @ahab4ik

Comment: yes, it works :) and one more question: it's add first `platform` from the list, and if i will need to add all available `platforms`, not first, can i save it?

Comment: You need to think about whether to use it as a json cast column or a separate table.

Comment: maybe you can give an example of using json in column?

Comment: @ahab4ikI think you need to create a new question. Because this is not enough on the comments.